# Regex - match first group regardless of second group

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to match all URIs (of some specific pattern) **without their suffix**.
My regex works when the address actually has a suffix, but I want it to also match cases where the suffix is already gone.

Regex:

```
(.+recordings\/.+)(\/.*)$
```

Matches:

```
https://somewebsite.com/recordings/10680-2162-4cff-991a-446ecff1/play
https://somewebsite.com/somethingsomething/recordings/10680-2162-4cff-991a-446ecff1/somesuffix
```

I'm trying to match this case as well:

```
https://somewebsite.com/recordings/10680-2162-4cff-991a-446ecff1
```

I've been playing with this for a couple of hours but unfortunately my knowledge of regex is limited.

[you can test my regex here](https://regex101.com/r/ZYiuKI/2)

Regex experts out there please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^(.*\/recordings\/.*?)(?:\/([^\/]*))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fkivnw/1)

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*\/recordings\/.*?)` - Group 1:

  - `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
  - `\/recordings\/` - a literal `/recordings/` string
  - `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?:\/([^\/]*))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching one or zero occurrences of

  - `\/` - a `/` char
  - `([^\/]*)` - Group 2: zero or more chars other than `/`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the `.+` at the end to `\S` to match non whitespace chars ad then optionally match the last part matching non whitespace chars without `/`

Depending on the regex delimiter, you don't have to escape `\/`

```
(\S+recordings\/[^\s\/]+)(?:\/[^\s\/]*)?$
```

- `(` Capture group 1

  - `\S+recordings\/[^\s\/]+`
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?:\/[^\s\/]*)?` Optionally match `/` and the rest of the line withtout `/`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XrGPW8/1)

Or match the protocol and optional non whitespace chars

```
^(https?:\/\/\S*\/recordings\/[^\s\/]+)(?:\/[^\s\/]*)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bjdiC1/1)